# Creating a dataframe with only 1 column out of a dataframe that contains 4 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains 4 columns (They are all part numbers). All I want is for this dataframe to have only 1 column that contains all the values from the 4 original columns (except the duplicates removed). This is what I have done. I don't get any error messages but for some reason I keep getting 4 columns instead of 1 single column when doing the merge. First I wrote this:

```
Supplier_Part_No = Supplier_Part_Numbers_Rename[['Supplier_Part_No']].copy()
Supplier_Part_No_1 = Supplier_Part_Numbers_Rename[['Supplier_Part_No..1']].copy()
Supplier_Part_No_2 = Supplier_Part_Numbers_Rename[['Supplier_Part_No..2']].copy()
Supplier_Part_No_3 = Supplier_Part_Numbers_Rename[['Supplier_Part_No..3']].copy()
```

That created 4 dataframes. Then I merge them back with the intention of getting one single column in a dataframe. I have no idea why it keeps giving me 4 instead, I also tried doing axis 1 that didn't help. No idea why its not giving me only 1 column but 4 instead:

```
Supplier_Parts_Combined = pd.concat([Supplier_Part_No, Supplier_Part_No_1,Supplier_Part_No_2, Supplier_Part_No_3], axis = 0)

Supplier_Parts_Combined
```

Comment: Do you want all the values in one column separated by comma?

Comment: no I don't want any separation of any kind, but yes all in 1 column

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

    A   B   C   D
0   1   4   2   2
1   4   0   3   2
2   1   0   1   0
3   3   4   3   4
4   0   2   4   2


df['merged'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(set(x)), axis = 1)

    A   B   C   D   new
0   1   4   2   2   241
1   4   0   3   2   2430
2   1   0   1   0   01
3   3   4   3   4   43
4   0   2   4   2   204
```

EDIT:

Consider this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val1': ['abc', np.nan], 'val2': ['xyz', 'pqr'], 'val3': ['lmn', 'abc'], 'val4': [np.nan, np.nan]})

    val1    val2    val3    val4
0   abc     xyz     lmn     NaN
1   NaN     pqr     abc     NaN

x = df.values.ravel()
np.unique(x[~pd.isnull(x)])
```

will give you

```
array(['abc', 'lmn', 'pqr', 'xyz'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow what your trying to do, I am trying to do this:                                     Supplier_Part I     Supplier_Part_2     Supplier Part_3

Comment: I am joining all the unique values in each row by using ''.join. Still not sure if thats what you want

Comment: It would be easier if you post your df.head() in the question

Comment: no I want something more basic then that. Say you have 3 columns that have 10 different values. I just want to have 1 column that has these 10 values in that column. For example column A contains 3 rows: 3, 5, 8. Column B contains 3 rows: 4, 7, 19, column C has 3 rows: 1, 2, 6. I want a column that has, 1, 2, 3, 4 5, 6, 7, 19 listed in the rows... That's all

Comment: any chance you can help? I have been trying to figure out this issue for a long time and have not gotten far. Thank you!

Comment: oh sorry, I should have specified I want it to show up in a pandas dataframe as well, the output.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) which reshapes data to long format with a variable name (former column name) and value column (former wide format column value). Since you only want one-column of no NAs, use `dropna` and `[[..]]` indexing:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """
Supplier_Part_1     Supplier_Part_2     Supplier_Part_3          
abc                        cde                        NA 
NA                         gbc                        NA 
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")
print(df)

#   Supplier_Part_1 Supplier_Part_2  Supplier_Part_3
# 0             abc             cde              NaN
# 1             NaN             gbc              NaN


rdf = pd.melt(df, var_name="Supplier_Part_ID", value_name="Supplier_Part").\
              dropna().reset_index()[['Supplier_Part']]
print(rdf)

#   Supplier_Part
# 0           abc
# 1           cde
# 2           gbc
```